# c# UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress is very slow on windows 7

Tags: c#

What could be the reason, and how can I solve the following issue:
I need to get the current user email address.
And I'm using this line:

```
string myString = UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress;
```

This executes in **1-2 secs** on **windows 10**, but on **windows 7** it takes up **1-2 MINUTES**!

Can anyone tell me the reason for this, and how can I solve this issue on windows 7?

Comment: Does both the application hit the same AD Server?

Comment: You sure it's because of Windows 7? Are both PCs configured exactly the same, are on the same domain, etc... Either way this seems like a very broad question which I assume could have a multitude of reasons for the cause?

Comment: The services are just slower, it's not the OS.

Comment: I'm using the application inside a multinational company. So all the settings should be the same on all computers (regarding server etc).
We checked the nslookup, and we have the same addresses.

I'm assuming that it is a windows 7 issue, is because I've tried it out with 4 of my colleagues, 2 of them has windows 7 and 2 of them has windows 10. Windows 7 users email address getting part is really slow, while with windows 10 users, its just a click.

Comment: I'm willing to bet money that you're hitting different domain controllers.

Comment: Hmm, after further investigating, it seems you're right Jeremy Thompson!